# Convert static website to dynamic based on nextjs

Tags: next.js, strapi

I have a static website with html, css pages :

1. Home
2. About
3. Compamy projects > Projects category 1, Projects category 2, Projects category 3
4. News > post news
5. Jobs : employment form
6. Contact : contact form

I want to make website be dynamic in navigation as I add any new page in future via headless cms appear in nav ? best scheme to do that via headless cms like strapi for example ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a dynamic navigation, you can use a single-type with a component or just use a collection type.

There are many approached on how to do this with Strapi but here are few examples.

In this first example I created a `single-type` content type with navbar component.

[image]

Which ever items I add to the navbar, those are the items that will appear on the front end.

[image]

I followed similar pattern for the navigation in the footer.

[image]

[image]

Here is what it look like in code.

First I get all my data from the global single-type component that I have.

```js
async function getGlobal(lang: string): Promise<any> {
  const token = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_TOKEN;

  if (!token) throw new Error("The Strapi API Token environment variable is not set.");

  const path = `/global`;
  const options = { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } };

  const urlParamsObject = {
    populate: [
      "metadata.shareImage",
      "favicon",
      "notificationBanner.link",
      "navbar.links",
      "navbar.navbarLogo.logoImg",
      "footer.footerLogo.logoImg",
      "footer.menuLinks",
      "footer.legalLinks",
      "footer.socialLinks",
      "footer.categories",
    ],
    locale: lang,
  };
  return await fetchAPI(path, urlParamsObject, options);
}
```

Then I pass that data to my components.

```js
  return (
    <html lang={params.lang}>
      <body>
        <Navbar
          links={navbar.links}
          logoUrl={navbarLogoUrl}
          logoText={navbar.navbarLogo.logoText}
        />

        <main className="dark:bg-black dark:text-gray-100 min-h-screen">
          {children}
        </main>

        <Banner data={notificationBanner} />

        <Footer
          logoUrl={footerLogoUrl}
          logoText={footer.footerLogo.logoText}
          menuLinks={footer.menuLinks}
          categoryLinks={footer.categories.data}
          legalLinks={footer.legalLinks}
          socialLinks={footer.socialLinks}
        />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Full code [here](https://github.com/strapi/nextjs-corporate-starter/blob/main/frontend/src/app/%5Blang%5D/layout.tsx)

All though this is dynamic, you still need to add these items inside the Strapi admin navbar and footer components.

To make this even more dynamic, you can just query the items directly. For instance lets say I have these pages.

[image]

Whenever I add a new page in Strapi it will automatically add it to the navigation.

If you make your navigation generated from the 'pages' collection type.

You can also include showInNavigation field, just incase you don't want some of the pages to show up in the nav.

To use your example

```
Compamy projects > Projects category 1, Projects category 2, Projects category 3
```

You can have a collection type 'ptojects' that has many 'categories' and each category has certain posts associated with them.

You would just query the projects collection type and use it to construct your nest menu, since you have all the data.

Let me know if this helped.

We also have open office hours on Strapis Discord channel mon-fri 12:30pm cst.  I hang out there a lot.  If you have follow up questions ask here or stop on by.

You can also checkout the whole project as a reference [here](https://github.com/strapi/nextjs-corporate-starter)

Also there is a plugin that allows you to build navigations, you can find it [here](https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-navigation)